# the eye of the needle in Spanish

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

Consider this sentence:

> Por fin, metí el hilo por el ojo de la aguja.
>
> Finally, I threaded the needle.

I understand that **el** **ojo** **de la aguja** is the Spanish for the eye (the little hole/loop at the base of a (sowing) needle through which the thread goes) here; but somehow I get a feeling that this is too long a phrase for colloquial use. What's the word used by native speakers for this? Please also mention your country so I understand if your translation has any regional application.

P.S. Please DO NOT quote RAE or any dictionary as I am more interested in finding out what the people speak in real life instead of what the books say.

Comment: It's `aguja`, not `abuja`.

Comment: That was a stupid typo, now corrected. Thanks!

Comment: In Cuba we say `ensartar` this means `meter el hilo por el ojo de la aguja`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To refer to the hole I don't think there is specific word, it's `el ojo de la aguja`. However, to refer to the action of inserting the thread in the hole, `enhebrar` is used.

> enhebrar.
>   1. tr. Pasar la hebra por el ojo de la aguja o por el agujero de las cuentas, perlas.

In a sentence:

> Para poder coser la costura primero tienes que enhebrar la aguja.

I'm from Spain.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent to "thread a needle" is "enhebrar" or "hilar", so: "Por fin enhebré la aguja", or "Por fin hilé la aguja"

Answer (score 2):

We use *el ojo de la aguja*. There's not a shorter translation.
I'm a native speaker from Chile.